# how to use same field to take data into uitextfield and out the result on label

Tags: iphone

i am writing an application for temperature converter in iphone i want use the same field for data input and output i.e single field which has properties of both uitextfield and uilabel. plz help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
-(IBAction)clculate
{
NSString *input =yourtetfield.text;  
Made some caculation   
................  
................  
 yourtetfield.text= result;  
}
```

Note result is a string .

Comment: it is giving an error    error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setText:'

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this....write this code on your buttonclick...

```
 -(IBAction)btnGoClicked:(id)sender
 {
     NSString *strTxtFiled = txtField.text;
     int intdata = [strTxtFiled intValue] * 2;
     txtField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",intdata];
 }
```

Here txtField is your TextField and I had done some calculation..you can do your calculation as explained here...

Answer (score 0):

well,you can use uitextfield. It has an input (with the text property) and an output (with setText: )
[Documentation of uitextfield](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)

Answer (score 0):

'myLabelVariable.text = myUITextfield.Text; is that what your on for?